# Windows Service to Extract HTML Data

Tags: c#, windows-services, visual-studio-2013, web-scraping

I'm trying to create a windows service that will take some information from a website every 5 minutes and place in a database.

I'm using Visual Studio 2013, writing the code in C# and the database is located in SQL Server 2008 r2.

In my service, I've written in a text document that updates with the website information for testing purposes. I know the code I've written for it is fine and will do what I want because I put it into an online C# compiler and I'm getting exactly what I'm looking for. The problem is that when I try to replicate this in Visual Studio and start my service it will either: 


A) Start, but will not add any information what-so-ever
B) Start and Stop immediately

The code I'm using is:

```
WebClient web = new WebClient();
String html = web.DownloadString("http://www.nalcorenergy.com/hydro/scrape1.asp");
```

Using the above code, I'm able to get the exact number I'm looking for and it appears in the online compiler. Once I plug this code in the service it doesn't have the same effect.
I'm not sure if this matters or not, but I have tried putting this code in both the `OnStart()` method and `ElapsedEventHandler()` portions and it makes no difference.

If anyone would be able to give me any advice on this matter it would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks for your time!

<-----------------------------------------------------EDIT------------------------------------------------------->

Here's my entire code that I'm using:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Timers;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net;


namespace WinServiceSample
{
public partial class ScheduledService : ServiceBase
{

    Timer timer;
    WebClient web;
    String html;


    public ScheduledService()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        web = new WebClient();
        timer = new Timer(60000);
        timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(timer_Elapsed);

    }

    void timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        html = web.DownloadString("http://nalcorenergy.com/hydro/scrape1.asp");
        TraceService(html + DateTime.Now);
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {

        TraceService("start service " + DateTime.Now);

        timer.Enabled = true;



    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        timer.Enabled = false;
        TraceService("stopping service " + DateTime.Now);
    }

    private void TraceService(string content)
    {

        FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"C:\Users\cbsfiander\Desktop\Services.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs);
        sw.BaseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.End);
        sw.WriteLine(content);
        sw.Flush();
        sw.Close();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Could you share a bit more of you code. Also are you getting any exceptions? What logic are you using to keep the service running after the initial call in OnStart?

Comment: @SpaceghostAli - My entire code that I'm working with is up now, with the exception of the Program.cs class which I kept to default. I'm not receiving any exceptions when the service actually starts and as you can see above I'm implementing a timer to keep the call going. Right now I have it set to a 1 min interval for testing purposes.

Comment: Add try/catch blocks in the timer_Elapsed and TraceService methods and attach the debugger to your service, I think you may be throwing an unhandled exception in there

Comment: I'll give it a shot and let you know

Comment: Finally was able to do this and I added try/catch blocks in the timer_Elapsed() method. I receive this error "The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive.
"
 So now I think I'm a bit more lost lol. Note: This is my first time coding in C# and using Visual Studio.. and making a Windows Service so please forgive me if I'm doing something horribly wrong

Comment: Which line throws the exception, is it the one with the call to DownloadString? Can you browse to that URL on the same machine and with the same account that the service is running as?

Comment: It is the DownloadString line that throws the exception, and on the same machine I'm using to create this service I can view that URL, even through Visual Studio itself. I've added in a proxy as well in case that could of been the problem but even that is throwing an exception now (InvalidCastException)

Comment: Post your updated code and the full Exception with a Stack Trace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I feel like an idiot now lol. 
I changed the original code a little bit and used an eventlog to store the information rather than output the data to a text file. I also changed the proxy settings in the App.config file for the service. Here is the new edited code:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Timers;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;

namespace WinServiceSample
{
public partial class ScheduledService : ServiceBase
{

    Timer timer;

    public ScheduledService()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        if (!System.Diagnostics.EventLog.SourceExists("MyLogSrc"))
        {
            System.Diagnostics.EventLog.CreateEventSource("MyLogSrc", "MyLog");
        }

        myEventLog.Source = "MyLogSrc";
        myEventLog.Log = "MyLog";
        timer = new Timer(10000);
        timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(timer_Elapsed);

    }

    void timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {

        WebClient wc = new WebClient();
        string reply = wc.DownloadString("http://www.nalcorenergy.com/hydro/scrape1.asp");
        myEventLog.WriteEntry(reply);

    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        myEventLog.WriteEntry("Its Started");


        timer.Enabled = true;

    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        timer.Enabled = false;

        myEventLog.WriteEntry("She no go");
    }



}
}
```

And now it works like a charm. Thanks for all your responses!!

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably want to implement a timer and have that call the code to download the HTML and not in OnStart()

Comment: I have already done that in the above code, my bad for not putting more up in the original post though, sorry about that. As you can see, I have implemented a timer to download the HTML and it is no longer in the OnStart() method and I'm still not getting anything in my log file

Comment: Try creating a timer helper, i.e., TimerHelper.cs, and place your timer code there.